# Controlling the Execution of Batch program running in different JVM on different server

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, jvm

I am having a Batch program (Program to insert / update / query Database) schedule using Java Timer to trigger one time a day. 
This Batch program runs in two different servers in apache tomcat.

Now My problem is that Java Timer API triggering the job parallely in both the servers, due to which my program getting executed twice, hence I am getting same record processed twice, with different Primary Key.

I need to make sure that my program triggers only once, that triggering should be happening dynamically irrespective of servers.
Once one Batch is started others should not get started or other should not get processed.

Here, 
Tomcat is hosted in two servers each has same application deployed in it
I am having one Database which is shared by both the servers.

Java and spring is used.

Need suggestion / help in solution for the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a job scheduling library, like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), which support running jobs in a clustered environment.
Quartz has the ability to make sure that exactly one node will run the job thus preventing duplicated execution of jobs. You can read more about this [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering).
Spring provides abstractions for asynchronous execution and scheduling of tasks with the TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler interfaces. Spring also features integration classes for supporting scheduling with the Quartz Scheduler. For more info take a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

If you wish to continue using Java timers you will have to take care of synchronization yourself. The commons solution is using shared lock database table. You have to be careful not to run into concurrency issues when 2 nodes try to read/write from the lock table at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, But I want the same to be achieved in Java Timer itself.